# Package object for type definintions

Tags: scala, package, type-definition

I'm still new to Scala and have a question about package object.

I have a package `com.pack.age.command` which contains the following trait:

```
trait Command

case object Help extends Command
```

Now, I would like to define a function to process commands:

```
type CommandArgument = scala.Any
type CommandProcessor = Command => CommandArgument => Unit
```

I tend to put these type definitions into a package object.

```
package object command {
  type CommandArgument = scala.Any
  type CommandProcessor = Command => CommandArgument => Unit
}
```

The reason is that these types are same for all commands so it looks pretty much logically to me.

But is it common to do like that in Scala?

Comment: Declaring type alias for such purposes is common, but using `Any` is not good. Maybe you'd better use a type parameter for `CommandArgument` when defining each `Command` subclass.

Comment: As @Naetmul says type `Any` is horrible. Take a look at the following rant about `akka` which I find instructive on this point: http://stew.vireo.org/posts/I-hate-akka/

Comment: @Naetmul Actually I wanted to use `Option[String]` as an argument but iwanted to provide more general type.

Comment: @Yaneeve Yes, I borrowed that from `akka`'s receiver. :)

Comment: @St.Antario ;-) Just as a disclaimer, I've had a generally pleasant experience using akka. Also take a look at their new initiative http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/typed.html

Answer (score 1):

Though I personally like type aliases, these things, I find are very subjective where some community members use them more than others.

Take a look at the following recommendations:

[Twitter's Effective Scala style guide](http://twitter.github.io/effectivescala/#Types%20and%20Generics-Type%20aliases)